# Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported. When using Python sockets on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, sockets, raspbian

I am using python sockets to send characters and receive a video stream from a Raspberry PI on py LAN. So far, everything works as intended. The videostream is being received from the pi and displayed on the PC. But I get an error whenever the PI connects to my PC (the PC is the server and the PI is the client). The error is:

```
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
```

Additional info:
I am running Ubuntu 19.10. My python version is 3.7. Attached below are both the server file and the client file.

```
import io
import socket
import struct
import cv2
import numpy as np


class Server:
    opened = False
    address = ''
    port = 0
    clientSocket = None
    connection = None
    socketServer = socket.socket()

    def __init__(self, address, port):
        self.address = address
        self.port = port

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.socketServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.socketServer.bind((self.address, self.port))  # ADD IP HERE
            print("Server: Opened and awaiting stream")
        except: print("Server: Failed to open StreamCollector")
        try:
            self.socketServer.listen(0)
            # self.clientSocket = self.socketServer.accept()[0].makefile('rb')
            self.clientSocket, address = self.socketServer.accept()
            self.connection = self.clientSocket.makefile('rb')
            self.opened = True
            print(f"Stream Initialized from {address}")
        except:
            self.close()
            print("Server: No stream was found")

    def getStreamImage(self):
        img = None
        try:
            image_len = struct.unpack('<L', self.connection.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
            imageStream = io.BytesIO()
            imageStream.write(self.connection.read(image_len))
            imageStream.seek(0)
            imageBytes = np.asarray(bytearray(imageStream.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
            img = cv2.imdecode(imageBytes, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        except:
            self.close()
            print("Server: Stream halted")
        return img

    def sendCommand(self, command):
        self.clientSocket.send(bytes(command, "ascii"))

    def close(self):
        try:
            if self.clientSocket is not None:
                self.clientSocket.close()
            if self.connection is not None:
                self.connection.close()
            self.socketServer.close()
            self.opened = False
            print("Server: Closed")
        except: print("Server: Failed to close")

    def isOpened(self):
        return self.opened


if __name__ == '__main__':
    host, port = '10.78.1.195', 8000
    # host, port = '10.17.26.78', 8000
    server = Server(host, port)
    server.connect()
    while server.isOpened():
        img = server.getStreamImage()
        cv2.imshow("stream", img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'): server.close()
```

Client:

```
import io
import socket
import struct
import time
import picamera

# create socket and bind host
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('10.78.1.195', 8000))
connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')

try:
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (320, 240)  # pi camera resolution
        camera.framerate = 15  # 15 frames/sec
        start = time.time()
        stream = io.BytesIO()

        # send jpeg format video stream
        for foo in camera.capture_continuous(stream, 'jpeg', use_video_port=True):
            connection.write(struct.pack('<L', stream.tell()))
            connection.flush()
            stream.seek(0)
            connection.write(stream.read())
            if time.time() - start > 600:
                break
            stream.seek(0)
            stream.truncate()
    connection.write(struct.pack('<L', 0))
finally:
    connection.close()
    client_socket.close()
```

If I can provide any additional information please let me know.

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998451/qt-session-management-error-with-matplotlib-pyplot-plot, If your program works then I recommend you ignore that error message.

Comment: @eyllanesc  I tried this, but I don't have a sessions directory or any other directories with names of python modules. Because the code is working, I agree the the error can be ignored, I would just like it to stop appearing. Thank you for the response!

Comment: @Mezex did you find a solution? In my case error occur when using imshow from opencv (program executes ok, but it cannot terminate normally: I need to kill it manually).

Comment: I get this error when I run cmake-gui on ubuntu-18.04 commond prompt. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this may help, although it's not exactly the same situation. I've gotten the same error when using `matplotlib` to display a plot running inside pycharm IDE, so it's possible the error could be coming from `cv2.imshow("stream", img)`.

For example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([i for i in range(10)])
plt.show()
```

Generates error (even though it still shows the plot):

```
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
```

Starting `pycharm` without the env variable SESSION_MANAGER causes the error to not occur — either unset it (`unset SESSION_MANAGER`), or unset it just to launch the program (eg, `python3`, `pycharm`, etc):

```
env -u SESSION_MANAGER pycharm-community
```

Comment: `env -u SESSION_MANAGER pycharm-professional &>/dev/null & disown`

Answer (score 3):

Run this command

```
unset SESSION_MANAGER
```

Comment: What does SESSION_MANAGER do? An explanation as to its usage and context would help all readers who encounter this question.

Comment: (ubuntu 20.04) it worked! thank you